# AdView failed to instantiate

Tags: android, admob, adview

I want to include an admob banner in my application and I got this weird error. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Here is the xml code

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    ads:adUnitId="..."
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
/>
```

In the activity, I wrote the following code

```
adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
adview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
adview.loadAd(re);
```

In the Logcat I get the following error

```
Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <0, 800>
```

I suspected that there must have been an additional problem since I gave the width of the AdView as "wrap_content"

In the graphical view of the xml file there is this warning

[image]

and when I click on this error I see that there is an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

If you want to investigate further here is the full exception stack trace

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getApplicationContext(BridgeContext.java:1272)
at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:155)
at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:329)
at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:397)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:165)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:205)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:133)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:83)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:86)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:454)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:367)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1323)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1077)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:903)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:399)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2743)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1429)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3629)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3284)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: The problem is going to be before run time.  I mean that your graphical view of the Layout needs to be working.  It should show "com.google...AdView" if it's working correctly.  I can't tell what's wrong with the rest of the layout.  If you put the whole thing here, someone - maybe me - could have a look.

Comment: your layout height and width might prevented it from showing it properly

Comment: Are you sure @xDragonZ, because I gave the width and height as wrap_content. And what do you think about the related UnsupportedOperationException? I guess this exception prevents ads from being shown and that's why I get "Not enough space" error. AdView do not hold any ads so the wrap_content property has 0 width.

Comment: Now it seems that I was wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adview request starts after the layout been created. So you have to provide specific height and width to the layout of give some weight to the layout. You are provided wrap_content to the hieght and width of the layout, So it takes initially as a 0dp of width and all the view elements loads in the page based on the that. just try with fixed layout size like this,

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    ads:adUnitId="..."
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
/>
```

And also you have to mention admob in the xmlns in the layout xml

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

In resources you have to declare the admob package like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Well, I didn't believe that this could solve my problem but it did indeed. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it. You just make the right dimensions of admob, it requires 480, 75.